# Asnyc Loop through URLs Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of URLs asynchronously however I'm finding that while this method would normally work using `axios.get(url)` that it's instead returning undefined when I try it using the post method.

Does anyone know why this might be the case - or else have a better method of async looping through a bunch of pages when making post requests?

```
const axios = require('axios');

let data = [];
let promises = [];

// 1. Import URLS
const urls = ['https://example.com/',
              'https://example.com/page-a.html',
              'https://example.com/page-b.html'];

// 2. Queue up the promises
urls.map(function(url) {
  promises.push(
    axios.post(`https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryRecord?key=${API_KEY}`, {
      url: url,
      metrics: ["first_contentful_paint",
                "first_input_delay",
                "largest_contentful_paint",
                "cumulative_layout_shift"],
      effectiveConnectionType: '4G',
      formFactor: 'ALL_FORM_FACTORS'
    })
  )
});

// 3. Return the responses
axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.map(function(res) {
      try {
        const { key, metrics } = res.record;
        console.log(metrics);
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Try logging `results`.

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated) say that `axios.all` is deprecated and to just use `Promise.all` instead.